# WPAlchemy MediaAccess "Add Media" button opens new page instead of pop up

Tags: wpalchemy

I'm using WPAlchemy for a custom meta box that lets you upload media. however the "Add Media" button is taking me to the "add media files to your computer..." as a new page (as if it were just a regular link) instead of opening as a pop-up on the same page. I tested my media upload button in a regular post situation and it popped up.

Comment: Okay, I solved it (again, cause this happened before but I forgot the solution!)....

This was for a custom post type and I hadn't added a support that involved uploading something. So, I added "thumbnail" to the list of supports...

'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail')
for my custom post and that did the trick! It's a weird little glitch. I hope to never make this mistake again!

Comment: I think that’s too good to know to hide it in a comment. Please write a real answer and mark your question as _answered_ (the ✔) then.

Comment: Thanks, I did just now. I tried to answer it right away but I didn't have enough points. Now I have to wait 2 days to accept my own answer. :(

Comment: Well, I hope you are still with us next week. :)

Comment: Thanks! I've been posting mostly on stack overflow and that's where I have a "better reputation" I think I'll post all my wordpress questions here exclusively. 
Did you have this problem too?

Comment: Not yet. It is just one of these details that are hard to google and good to know.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay, I solved it (again, cause this happened before but I forgot the solution!)....

This was for a custom post type and I hadn't added a support that involved uploading something. So, I added "thumbnail" to the list of supports...

```
'supports' => array('title','author','thumbnail')
```

for my custom post and that did the trick! It's a weird little glitch. I hope to

Comment: Please accept your own answer so this question goes out of the "Unanswered" flow.

Comment: I just did. I couldn't before though, I didn't have a high enough reputation.

Comment: @Stratboy Sweet! If your using Wordpress I highly recommend Advanced Custom fields. I've been using it for a while now and love it!

Comment: @Tiffany! I'll give it a try! Did you ever tried it along with Polylang? If yes, does it work well?

Comment: @Stratboy no I never tried Polylang

Comment: I tried it, it works.